# Running macros through code on server: Wrong path to excel file?

Tags: c#, vba, excel, path

In my application I open a .xlsm file with a macro (copies data to .xlsm file) and a .xlsx file that executes that macro. Let's say my files are called `FileWithMacro.xlsm` and `FileThatExecutesMacro.xlsx`. I need this application on a server but have developed it locally. To debug the application, I put my files to `C:\Users\myUser\Documents\`.

I'm opening the `FileWithMacro.xlsm` like this:

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(serverPath + "FileWithMacro.xlsm");
Excel._Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets["FileThatExecutesMacro"];
```

After that, I call the method that runs the macro:

```
RunMacro(serverPath + "FileThatExecutesMacro.xlsx");
```

My method looks like this:

```
private static void RunMacro(string source)
{
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(source);
    Excel._Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
    worksheet.Activate();

    try
    {
        excelThatRunsMacro.Run("FileWithMacro.xlsm!MyMacro");
        workbook.Save();
        excelThatRunsMacro.Quit();
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Locally the macros work without any problems. When I change all the paths and copy the output of my code to the server (\\myServer\someUrl...), I'm getting the following exception:

> 'C:\Users\**myServerUser**\Documents\FileWithMacro.xlsm' could not be found.

Although I changed all my paths to the correct server location (and I am **really sure** that there is no local path in my code and in the macro anymore). I even deleted my `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuilt the project but that didn't change anything. I even created a new project and built it without using local paths but I got the same error. What am I doing wrong? Is `excel.Run` by default searching the macro in the `Documents` folder?

Or is the problem because of the line `Windows("FileWithMacro.xlsm").Activate` in my macro? When running the macro manually, it works fine. It just doesn't work when running it through the code.

Comment: Is `FileWithMacro.xlsm` opened from the server before this?

Comment: @R3uK Yes, I open it directly on the server.

Comment: It's strange that it isn't detected if it's opened... You could try to rename the VBAProject in `FileWithMacro.xlsm` and call directly like this `[MyProject.vbp].[MyModule].MyMacro`

Comment: @R3uK The problem is that the files get refreshed each month. If I'd rename the VBAProject, I'd have to rename it again next month and so on...

Comment: You could do it programmatically : `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.Name = "projTest"` See: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx Not sure if it's the best option, maybe somebody will have an easier solution!

Comment: Probably need to see a bit more of your code...

Comment: @diiN__________ : Did you find a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find out why I got the exception. However, I've found a workaround. Before executing the macro, I copy the `FileWithMacro.xlsm` to the location in the error message. When I then used the code like I've had it, I've got a message that the `FileWithMacro.xlsm` is already in use. To fix this, I just had to pass the `Excel.Application` to my method and use this instance instead of creating a new one:

```
private static void RunMacro(Excel.Application excel, string source)
```